# Cannot resolve symbol 'ShowListener'

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I don't know why i have tow errors one at `ClickListener()` and `ShowListener()`? I am trying to like OnItemClickListener but for **MeowBottomNavigation**

```
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    bottomNavigation =findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigation);
    bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(1, R.drawable.ic_baseline_message));
    bottomNavigation.add(new MeowBottomNavigation.Model(2, R.drawable.ic_settings));
    bottomNavigation.add(newMeowBottomNavigation.Model(3,R.drawable.ic_baseline_account_circle_24));

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, new FragmentChatt()).commit();
    bottomNavigation.setOnClickMenuListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.**ClickListener()** {

        public void onClickItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked item"+item.getId(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener(new MeowBottomNavigation.**ShowListener()** {

        public void onShowItem(MeowBottomNavigation.Model item) {
            Fragment select_fragment=null;
            switch (item.getId()){
                case ID_CHAT:
                    select_fragment=new FragmentChatt();
                    break;
                case ID_SETTINGS:
                    select_fragment=new FragmentSettengs();
                    break;
                case ID_ACOUNT:
                    select_fragment=new FragmentAcount();
                    break;


            }
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,select_fragment).commit();
        }
    });


  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post now, but for anyone who's still having the same problem check your module implementation in build.gradle file.
Here's the a dependency that worked for me:

```
dependencies {  
 implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation-java:1.2.0'
}
```

You can also check their github:

[Documentation](https://github.com/oneHamidreza/MeowBottomNavigationJava)

But that is a **deprecated** solution, so here's the new one they recommend [New Documentation](https://github.com/oneHamidreza/MeowBottomNavigation).

If you want to use the new solution, you need to implement the dependency:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.etebarian:meow-bottom-navigation:1.3.1'
}
```

And change the **setOnShowListener** and **setOnClickMenuListener** methods with:

```
bottomNavigation.setOnClickMenuListener(new Function1<MeowBottomNavigation.Model, Unit>() {
            @Override
            public Unit invoke(MeowBottomNavigation.Model model) {
                // YOUR CODES
                return null;
            }
        });

bottomNavigation.setOnShowListener(new Function1<MeowBottomNavigation.Model, Unit>() {
            @Override
            public Unit invoke(MeowBottomNavigation.Model model) {
                // YOUR CODES
                return null;
            }
        });
```

Comment: your answer would be even better if you'd add code for the new solution as well or elaborate on it, instead of just linking to a remote repository